# ThreeJS - Project texture onto mesh surface

Tags: javascript, three.js, map-projections

I'm looking to project a texture onto the surface of a mesh in ThreeJS.

https://www.lanyardmarket.com/en/printed-tshirt

This link achieves the result i'm looking for however i'm not sure how they achieved it.

.

I'll update this post as I research however if anyone knows how to project a ThreeJS texture onto a mesh i'd love to know.

Thanks

Comment: https://cdn.rawgit.com/usefulthink/three.js/projector-lights-preview/examples/webgl_lights_projectorlight.html

Comment: How about: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_decals.html

Answer (score 5):

Working example you may find here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/pcjbysn1/

[image: threejs box texture UV coordinates mapping]

BufferGeometry stores texture coordinates in 'uv' attribute, you can add it with [BufferGeometry.addAttribute](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.addAttribute) and access it through `geom.attributes.uv.array`.

```
let uvcoords = [];
let vertexCount = geom.attributes.position.array.length / 3;

// allocate array of UV coordinates (2 floats per each vertex)
uvcoords.length = 2 * vertCount;

if (geom.attributes.uv === undefined) {
    geom.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvcoords, 2));
}
```

Now all you need is to "project" mesh vertices onto some 3D plane. These projection coordinates will appear your UV coordinates.

[image: Projecting mesh vertices on texture UV space (generate uv coordinates)]

In general case, you would need to do [Plane.projectPoint](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Plane.projectPoint) for each vertex. This approach is straightforward and can be optimized with pre-rotating the mesh so that vertex x and y components become u and v accordingly. This you will find in my jsfiddle.